# Is it possible to move the text from an element to another using jquery animation?

Tags: jquery

Given this html code

```
<div id="div1">
    Some Text
</div>

<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Is it possible to animate "Some Text" from div1 to div2? I would like to move just the text rather than the whole element.

Comment: can you elaborate more on a real life scenario you are trying to accomplish and there might be a better solution out there. For the time being you could do what Drew has mentioned below

Comment: Well I'm building a UI for a game of chess. I'd like to animate the opponent's move by dragging the piece (an ascii text character) from one square to another. I've got draggable and droppable events hooked to the containers so I'd like not to touch them if possible. ShankarSangoli's reply seems to be the best option thought its a different type of animation I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, though you'll need to create a wrapper to do the animation...

***Here's a demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TuuvF/1/

```
var div2 = $('#div2');

var wrapper = $('#div1')
    .contents()
    .wrap($('<div>').css('position','absolute'))
    .parent();

wrapper.animate(div2.offset(), 1000, function() {
    $(this).contents().appendTo(div2);
    wrapper.remove();
});
```

---

Here's the play by play explanation...

```
    // reference div2
var div2 = $('#div2');

   // reference div1
var wrapper = $('#div1')

      // grab all of its contents (including text nodes)
    .contents()

      // wrap the contents in a generic wrapper div with absolute positioning
    .wrap($('<div>').css('position','absolute'))

      // traverse up to the wrapper div
    .parent();

  // animate the wrapper using the coordinates of div2 provided by .offset()
wrapper.animate(div2.offset(), 1000, function() {

        // in the animation callback, empty the contents into div2
    $(this).contents().appendTo(div2);

        // remove the now empty wrapper
    wrapper.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
$('#div1').slideUp('slow', function(){
     var div1Content = $(this).html();//Get div1's content
     $(this).html('');//Clear div1's content
     $('#div2')
     .hide()//Hide div2
     .html(div1Content)//Set div2's content
     .slideDown('slow');//Slidedown to show the content
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/GddSW/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "animate" it... you can take the text and put it into the other div..

Best solution would be to animate the element, maybe animate it then swap the content, then reset the original div?

Comment: Actually you can animate it, well, to make it look animated anyway

Comment: Your answer starts with "You can't really animate it", when you can really animate it. He hasn't asked if animating text is possible, he has asked how he can animate something from one element to the next. If he asked "can u animate text?" you could write "you can't really animate it"..

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate text directly, but you can make it seem that you are animating it.  You could hide the destination `div` and then show it using an animation.

```
var content = $('#div1').html();
$('#div2').hide().html(content).show('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9gEk/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest putting the text in a sub element (maybe a span or something), using jQuery to get the position (offset/coordinates), then set that span to position absolute and the position with the previously mentioned offset, then you can do the animation, with a callback of replacing the div 2's content with the animated content and put position back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

that's a little tricky, you could grab the text, pop it into a absolute positioned div with a z-index so it floats over the page, then animate that div to the target area & insert the text into the target div. Here is a rough example off the top of my head. I've tested it and it works well.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>index</title>
<style type="text/css">
#anim-shell {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function($) {
    setTimeout("animate_text('#div1', '#div2')", 3000);
});

function animate_text( source_id, target_id )
{
    var _text = $(source_id).text();
    var soff = $(source_id).offset();
    var eoff = $(target_id).offset();
    $('<div id="anim-shell"></div>').appendTo('body');
    $('#anim-shell').css( { top: soff.top, left: soff.left } );
    $('#anim-shell').html( _text );
    $(source_id).text('');
    $('#anim-shell').animate( { top: eoff.top+'px', left: eoff.left+'px' }, 400, function() {
        $('#anim-shell').remove();
        $(target_id).text( _text );
    });
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="height: 20px; width: 30px;">test</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="div2" style="background: #ccc; width: 30px; height: 20px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```